# Convert String Date in yyyy-MM-dd into Java UtilDatein format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to take a date value as String in the format yyyy-MM-dd and return a jabva util date in the same format. 
for this I am using below code , but the result is coming as "Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 CEST 2013"

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String  strdate = "2013-09-18";
    Date utilDate = sdf.parse(strdate);
    System.out.println(utilDate);
```

Do i need to consider the locale also ?
Please help to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The result of `sdf.parse(strdate)` is just a string; assigning it to `utilDate` parses the string into a new `Date` object. At no point is the formatting information transferred.

Comment: You format the String to a Date but not the output back to a String in the wanted format

Comment: Simply do `System.out.println(sdf.format(utilDate));`

Comment: You might want to consider switching to LocalDate and DateFormatter classes from Java 8. It is the way to go. SimpleDateFormat is outdated

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: use java8 DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: @GauravRai1512 That standard ISO 8601 format is used by default in the `LocalDate` class. No need to define a formatting pattern, no need to use `DateTimeFormatter`. Just use: `LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" )`

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code.
You also have to format your simpleDateFormat object and pass utilDate object inside it to create formatted date as specified by you.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String  strdate = "2013-09-18";
            Date utilDate = sdf.parse(strdate);
            String date=sdf.format(utilDate );
            System.out.println(date);
 }
}
```

We can also implement through Java8 like below:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
         String  strdate = "2013-09-18";
            DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strdate, formatter);
            System.out.println(date.format(formatter));
}

}
```

or you can also use only LocalDate to change in java util like below.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class TestCircle {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String  strdate = "2013-09-18";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strdate);
        System.out.println(date);
    }

}
```